# throw new TypeError('I - node_modules/semver/semver.js:296

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Yesterday, this error started in two projects, which solution is feasible?

```
node_modules/yo

Output:
/Users/mac/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/semver/semver.js:296
    throw new TypeError('I
                    ^^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

Comment: can you give some more context? Not sure what you're asking

Comment: @NathanWright apparently this errors is popping over when you try to start something that uses that semver module to do any type of check. In his case, it is yargs. But that is not restricted to yargs, i'm having those same problems with other modules that depends on semver.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the download of semver cached, then I execute the command `yarn cache clean` in the folder of the project and solved.

Thanks